# svn: Can't create directory '/subversion/main/db/transactions/0-1.txn': Permission denied

Tags: svn, permissions

I created a local subversion directory and I'm having problems. I tried checking in my first file with the following command:

```
svn ci TestCommenterParseFilter.java
```

and I got the following error message

```
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Can't create directory '/export/svn/db/transactions/1-1.txn': Permission denied
svn: Your commit message was left in a temporary file:
svn:    '/export/speedplane/nutch-0.9/src/plugin/commenter/src/test/org/commenter/nutch/svn-commit.tmp'
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem, but if I created the directories "transactions" and "txn-protorevs" it worked afterwards without complaining.

Comment: This worked for me. I was restoring from a backup created from the python backup script (hot-backup.py) and these two folders were not included under the db folder in the backup. Once I made them on the SVN server in the restore repository, then everything committed correctly from my remote dev PC. Thanks! (Note: In my case this is all Windows - 2008 RC2 running SVN and XP on my dev PC).

Comment: right on! manually creating .../db/transactions and .../db/txn-protorevs after restoring from a hotbackup.py did the trick!

Answer (score 5):

The "permission denied" error, and the pathnames you have used, indicate that your user account doesn't have file permission to write to the `/export/svn` directory tree. There are at least two approaches to solving this:

1. Change the file permissions (perhaps with a group +w bit) on `/export/svn` so that you can write to the files. This is finicky and doesn't always stick.
2. Set up `svnserve` as a server process that you talk to using the `svn://` protocol. In this case the server process is the only one that needs to have write (or read) access to the repository directory.

Comment: If the svn server is set up to be used over ssh, the repository is (usually) accessed as the logged in ssh user. Therefore, all svn users should be in the same user group, and this user group should have group write access to the repository. Add write access for the group using `chmod -R g+w <repository_folder>`.

Answer (score 2):

Just make sure you start the svnserve -d and start it as root

Comment: Don't. First, option -d is not feasible when svn is used over shh. Second, don't run svn as root, but use an svn user to do so (usually _svn).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it'll fix the issue (usually gives a different error message) -- but still something to try...

Make sure you include a commit message (`-m` or `-F` options):

```
$ svn ci TestCommenterParseFilter.java -m "Commit message."

$ svn ci TestCommenterParseFilter.java -F commit_message.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers could really help me. I just had to give full permission to that folder:

[image]

Comment: 1. You should not set permissions to Users group. This is a security problem - you are exposing repository contents to all users. 2. You need to set permissions for the service account that runs your Subversion server. 3. If you use VisualSVN Server, read https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00037/

Comment: Generally speaking, I agree with you, but not in my case, as only I use my computer (GFIPT0479). That is our policy.